# Logical operators' precedence in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
    ++a || ++b && ++c;
    printf("%d %d %d", a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

The outputs are `1`, `0`, `0` by gcc 8.1.0. The `&&`‘s precedence should higher than `||`.

Why are the `b` and `c` are still `0`?

Comment: Because of *short-circuiting*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are three issues here:

1. Order of precedence.
2. Order of evaluation.
3. Short circuiting of logical operators.

Order of precedence implies that `++a || ++b && ++c` is evaluated as `++a || (++b && ++c)`.

However, due to the short circuiting requirements of logical operators, `++a` is evaluated first. Only if that evaluates to `false` will `(++b && ++c)` be evaluated. In your case, `++a` evaluates to `true`. Hence, `(++b && ++c)` is never evaluated.

Answer (score 14):

The expression `++a || ++b && ++c` is *grouped* as `++a || (++b && ++c)`. **But**, the right hand side of `||` is only evaluated if `++a` is `0`, which it isn't.

Comment: Isn't the expression in bracket should be calculated before "||"?

Comment: @EricShi **Absolutely not**. The left hand side of `||` is evaluated first.

Comment: @EricShi You are confusing precedence with order of evaluation...

Comment: @EugeneSh. spot on and very important.

Comment: @EricShi, It should be evaluated before `||`, but `++a` isn't `||`, it's an operand of that.

Answer (score 2):

The logical OR operator `||` (as well as the logical AND operator `&&`) is one of the few operators that perform *short circut operation*.

Section 6.5.14 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) says the following about the logical OR operator:

> *4* Unlike the bitwise `|` operator, the `||` operator guarantees
>   left-to-right evaluation; if the second operand is evaluated, there is
>   a sequence point between the evaluations of the first and second
>   operands. **If the first operand compares unequal to 0, the second
>   operand is not evaluated.**

Because `++a` evaluates to 1, the result of the `||` operator is guaranteed to be 1 and the right hand side is not evaluated.  Also, because `&&` has higher precedence than `||`, the right side of the `||` operator is `++b && ++c`, meaning that neither `++b` or `++c` is evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Precedence only controls how expressions are *parsed*, not how they are evaluated.  Arithmetic `*` has higher precedence than `+`, so `a * b + c` is parsed as `(a * b) + c`.  However, each of `a`, `b`, and `c` may be evaluated in any order.  The result of `a * b` must be known before it can be added to the result of `c`, but that doesn't mean that `a * b` must be evaluated *before* `c`.

Secondly, unlike most operators in C, the `||` and `&&` operators force left-to-right evaluation.  An expression like `a || b && c` will be parsed as `a || (b && c)`, but `a` will *always* be evaluated first, and `b && c` will only be evaluated if the result of `a` is 0.

Answer (score 0):

As far as precedence goes, `x || y && z` acts just like `x + y * z`: the second operator binds more tightly than the first one, and those expressions are equivalent to `x || (y && z)` and `x + (y * z)`, respectively.

The reason that `b` and `c` in the question aren't incremented is because, in addition to precedence, logical operations short circuit: once you've gotten far enough along to know the result, the rest of the expression is skipped. Both `||` and `&&` evaluate their arguments left-to-right, so in `a() || b()` and in `a() && b()`, the call to `a()` occurs before the call to `b()`.

In simple cases, if `a()` returns `true`, then in the expression `a() || b()` the call to `b()` will not be executed, because it won't affect the result. Similarly, if `a()` returns `false`, then in the expression `a() && b()`, the call to `b()` will not be executed.

In the code in the example, the increments to `b` and `c` won't be performed, because `++a` produces a non-zero value, so the result of the expression is `true` without needing to evaluate anything after `++a`.

Answer (score -1):

Operator precedence has nothing to do with order of evaluation. Precedence is the priority for grouping different types of operators with their operands.

So, the expression

```
++a || ++b && ++c;
```

will be evaluated as

```
++a || (++b && ++c);
```

Logical AND and Logical OR operator constitute **[sequence points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point)** and therefore guarantee a particular order of evaluation for their operands which is *left to right*.

[**Order of evaluation**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order):

> **Ordering**
>   ......
>
> - If a sequence point is present between the subexpressions E1 and E2,
>     then both value computation and side effects of E1 are
>     sequenced-before every value computation and side effect of E2
>
> **Rules**
>   .....
>   2) There is a sequence point after evaluation of the first (left) operand and before evaluation of the second (right) operand of the following binary operators: && (logical AND), || (logical OR), and , (comma).

Logical OR operation `(expr1 || expr2)` employs [**short-circuiting**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) behavior. That is, `expr2` is not evaluated if `expr1` is logical `1` `(true)`.

The initial value of `a`, `b` and `c` is `0`. In the expression:

```
++a || ++b && ++c;
```

`++a` -> pre-increment `a`.
That means, the value of the expression `++a` is resulting incremented value of `a` which will be `1`. Since, `||` operator employs short-circuit behavior, the right hand side expression of `||` will not be evaluated. Hence, you are getting output - `1 0 0`.

---

For better understanding, just try to change the `++a` -> `a++` in the expression.
The post increment operator also increase the value of operand by `1` but the value of the expression is the operand's original value prior to the increment operation. So, `a++` will be evaluated to `0` and because of short-circuit behavior the right hand side expression of `||` operator (`++b && ++c`) will be evaluated.

The logical AND operation (`expr1 && expr2`) also employs short-circuiting behavior. With logical short-circuiting, the second operand, `expr2`, is evaluated only when the result is not fully determined by the first operand, `expr1`. That is, `expr2` will be evaluated only if `expr1` is logical `1` `(true)` and `++b` will result in `1`. So, if you do

```
a++ || ++b && ++c;
^^^
```

The output would be - `1 1 1`.